# Debug desktop environment run

Tags: lightdm, desktop-environments, display-manager, pantheon

I've installed a Pantheon desktop environment (the one from elementaryOS) over Ubuntu 18.04 and now I have an issue staring this DE from lightdm. Particularly when I'm choosing Pantheon DE from lightdm menu before login, enter password and then press enter/login, screen becomes dark, and it returns back to the lightdm.

How can I debug this issue? How can I run DE directly from the tty1 without running display manager and see what is going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I know how to:

```
startx /usr/bin/ghome-session --session=pantheon
```